# Error using reactivemongo 0.12.1 with play 2.5.X

Tags: mongodb, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, play-reactivemongo

I tried upgrading to reactive mongo 0.12.1 with play 2.5.12 but when I run the JVM quits on me and I get the following stack trace:

Uncaught error from thread [application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] shutting down JVM since 'akka.jvm-exit-on-fatal-error' is enabled for ActorSystem[application] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: play/api/libs/concurrent/StateMachine   at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)  at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)  at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)     at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)   at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)   at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)    at play.api.libs.streams.impl.EnumeratorSubscriptionFactory$class.createSubscription(EnumeratorPublisher.scala:25)  at play.api.libs.streams.impl.EnumeratorPublisher.createSubscription(EnumeratorPublisher.scala:33)  at play.api.libs.streams.impl.EnumeratorPublisher.createSubscription(EnumeratorPublisher.scala:33)  at play.api.libs.streams.impl.RelaxedPublisher.subscribe(RelaxedPublisher.scala:19)     at akka.stream.impl.MaterializerSession.akka$stream$impl$MaterializerSession$$doSubscribe(StreamLayout.scala:1033)  at akka.stream.impl.MaterializerSession.assignPort(StreamLayout.scala:1025)     at akka.stream.impl.MaterializerSession$$anonfun$exitScope$2.apply(StreamLayout.scala:907)  at akka.stream.impl.MaterializerSession$$anonfun$exitScope$2.apply(StreamLayout.scala:906)  at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)  at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)   at akka.stream.impl.MaterializerSession.exitScope(StreamLayout.scala:906)   at akka.stream.impl.MaterializerSession$$anonfun$materializeModule$1.apply(StreamLayout.scala:958)  at akka.stream.impl.MaterializerSession$$anonfun$materializeModule$1.apply(StreamLayout.scala:950)  at scala.collection.immutable.Set$Set3.foreach(Set.scala:163)   at akka.stream.impl.MaterializerSession.materializeModule(StreamLayout.scala:950)   at akka.stream.impl.MaterializerSession.materialize(StreamLayout.scala:917)     at akka.stream.impl.ActorMaterializerImpl.materialize(ActorMaterializerImpl.scala:256)  at akka.stream.impl.ActorMaterializerImpl.materialize(ActorMaterializerImpl.scala:146)  at akka.stream.scaladsl.RunnableGraph.run(Flow.scala:350)   at akka.stream.scaladsl.Source.runWith(Source.scala:81)     at play.core.server.netty.NettyModelConversion.play$core$server$netty$NettyModelConversion$$createChunkedResponse(NettyModelConversion.scala:256)   at play.core.server.netty.NettyModelConversion$$anonfun$convertResult$1.apply(NettyModelConversion.scala:189)   at play.core.server.netty.NettyModelConversion$$anonfun$convertResult$1.apply(NettyModelConversion.scala:166)   at play.core.server.common.ServerResultUtils$.resultConversionWithErrorHandling(ServerResultUtils.scala:127)    at play.core.server.netty.NettyModelConversion.convertResult(NettyModelConversion.scala:235)    at play.core.server.netty.PlayRequestHandler$$anonfun$play$core$server$netty$PlayRequestHandler$$handleAction$2$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(PlayRequestHandler.scala:273)    at play.core.server.netty.PlayRequestHandler$$anonfun$play$core$server$netty$PlayRequestHandler$$handleAction$2$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(PlayRequestHandler.scala:267)    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(Future.scala:253)   at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(Future.scala:251)   at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32)     at play.api.libs.iteratee.Execution$trampoline$.executeScheduled(Execution.scala:110)   at play.api.libs.iteratee.Execution$trampoline$.execute(Execution.scala:70)     at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.executeWithValue(Promise.scala:40)    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryComplete(Promise.scala:248)  at scala.concurrent.Promise$class.complete(Promise.scala:55)    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.complete(Promise.scala:153)     at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$andThen$1.apply(Future.scala:436)   at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$andThen$1.apply(Future.scala:435)   at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32)     at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$AbstractBatch.processBatch(BatchingExecutor.scala:55)     at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(BatchingExecutor.scala:91)     at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(BatchingExecutor.scala:91)    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(BatchingExecutor.scala:91)    at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$.withBlockContext(BlockContext.scala:72)   at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch.run(BatchingExecutor.scala:90)     at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:39)    at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:415)   at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)     at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)     at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)     at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107) Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: play.api.libs.concurrent.StateMachine

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Make sure there is no issue with the Iteratees dependency pulled. ReactiveMongo for Play expect it to be provided by Play itself, from 2.4 to 2.6.

Comment: Thank you. It was exactly the problem! I ended up excluding iteratees from reactivemongo -

"org.reactivemongo" %% "play2-reactivemongo" % reactiveMongoVersion excludeAll(
        ExclusionRule("com.typesafe.play", "play-iteratees_2.11") // This is needed - otherewise version 2.6.1 overrides everything and kills play
      ),

Comment: Play ReactiveMongo already exclude the play dependencies, so this should not be the cause

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After examining the dependencies graph (https://github.com/jrudolph/sbt-dependency-graph), What ended up working for me is to exclude play-iteratees from ReactiveMongo.

In my build.sbt, change the import to:

```
"org.reactivemongo" %% "play2-reactivemongo" % reactiveMongoVersion excludeAll( ExclusionRule("com.typesafe.play", "play-iteratees_2.11")
```